# Xcode doesn't launch the watchOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, watchos, watchos-simulator

**Problem**

Xcode (9.4.1) doesn't launch the Simulator app at all when I try to run a watchOS app.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Select the scheme

[image: Select the scheme]

2. Hit run

[image: Hit run]

3. Build succeeds, waiting to attach.

[image: Waiting to attach]

4. And here is where it gets stuck. Nothing happens from here. The Simulator app never gets launched.

[image: Simulator not launched]

**Simulator Launch Workaround**

The Simulator can be opened manually. Then, Xcode installs the watchOS app on the watchOS Simulator and the iOS app on the iOS Simulator.

But here is the next problem: Once it has installed the apps it doesn't launch the watchOS app, even though i've set the launch to *Automatically* in the Scheme Editor.

[image: Launch option in Scheme editor]

**watchOS App Launch Workaround**

Go to the watchOS home screen and tap the app icon to open it.

---

I know that all the workarounds should not be necessary. And it all worked before.

**Other information:**

- I had installed the Xcode 10 beta 3 recently but I removed it already
- I removed the derived data

Answer (score 0):

I had to virtually connect the watch and phone via simulator to get it running. Like you would on iPhone to get it connected.

I found it odd but after that I had no issues. Go to the watch app via the iPhone simulator and pair the virtual watch then Presto!